# How to check uniqueness of a subgroup from its order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I came across the following question.

Let $|G|=28$ and assume there exists $H≤G$ with $|H|= 7$ then show that it is unique and normal subgroup of $G$.

Now if I can I show that $H$ is unique subgroup of order $7$ then it follows that $H$ is normal. But the converse is not true. So that means there has to be a way to know $H$ is unique subgroup only from its order, or so I think.

(However, I'm also aware that in this case, it actually suffices to show that $H$ is normal subgroup of $G$ since $\text{gcd}(|G|, |G:H|) =1$, we have that $H$ is unique.)

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to **check** the uniqueness of a subgroup? Especially if the only information given is it's order?
2. If not, then how does one proceed with such a question *in general* when the only information given is, the order of the groups, involved?

Comment: This looks like a job for Sylow's theorems.

Comment: The duplicate gives a proof with and without Sylow, i.e., that $H$ is normal.

Comment: @Shaun Is that like... some advanced theorem that a beginner like me shouldn't be fighting with? I'll check it out anyway.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is NOT a duplicate. I'm asking two questions that are entirely different than that one? The only thing duplicate here is that problem but that's not my question.

Comment: William, didn't you say "However, I'm also aware that in this case, it actually suffices to show that $H$ is normal subgroup "? Then it is unique of course by Sylow II. Have you seen the answer by azimut?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have written that in brackets to SHOW that I know it suffices to show that proving normal subgroup is enough but I have clearly written down TWO questions, EXPLICITLY. Are you just going to ignore that?

Comment: No, I am not ignoring that. Both questions are answered by azimut. By Sylow, the group order $28=4\cdot 7$ says that $H$ is unique. This works in general.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, but the purpose of this question is to not just solve that problem but also understand a general thought process. Please read the two questions I have explicitly asked, too.

Comment: The general thought process is just Sylow I,II and III. Have a look.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Okay then, give me some time to see what those theorems are and I'll get back to you.

Comment: No problem. You can also pose a new question then with a more specific case of $2.$, which is hard in general, and only works easily for "some" orders. Otherwise the classification of finite groups would be much easier. So we cannot expect an easy approach "in general". But this would be a different question, and so far too broad.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks! Took me some time to understand the proofs of Sylow theorems because I had to first catch up with the tools required to prove it. The answer is simple because $|H|=7$ implies $H$ is Sylow $7$-subgroup in this case, and number of $7$-SSG is of the form $1+7k$ such that $1+7k \big| |G|$ or rather $1+7k| 4$ since $\text{gcd}(1+pk, p^r) =1 $ for positive $r$ and so we have a unique subgroup because only $k=0$ satisfies that.